# dijkstra algorithm, run only one time for shortest paths of some nodes (not two, not the whole graph)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

So, dijkstra algorithm is (the best one) used to search for the shortest path of a weighted(without negative) and connected graph. Dijkstra algorithm can be used to find the shortest path of two points/vertices. AND it can be used to find the shortest path of all the vertices.

questions:
is my understanding correct? 
Can it also be used to find the shortest paths of some pair of vertices ? for example, the graph has A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K.  and we are only interested in the shortest paths of A,B ; C,K. it that possible we only turn the algorithm only one time to find out two paths?

Comment: "*the best one*" - not at all. It is a good concept and heavily used for many other similar algorithms. There are many variants, like A*, Arc-Flags, and others. But raw Dijkstra is super slow since it equally searchs in all directions.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run **two** Dijkstras. One starting from `A` and one from `C`.

What you could do is to run it from `{A, C}` (a *set Dijkstra*) until you have found paths to `B` and `K`. But that is no guarantee that the resulting paths are actually from `A` to `B` and `C` to `K`, it could as well be `C, B` and `C, K`. Actually, all combinations of `{A, C}, B` and `{A, C}, K` are then possible.

---

> *the best one*

Not at all. It is a good concept and heavily used for many other similar algorithms. There are many variants, like A*, Arc-Flags, and others. But raw Dijkstra is super slow since it equally searches in all directions.

Imagine a query where you have modeled the whole world. Your destination is `1 hour` away. Then Dijkstra will find shortest paths to **all nodes** that can be reached in `1 hour`. So it will also consider a short flight to your neighboring country, even if it's the totally wrong direction. The algorithm `A*` is a simple modification of Dijkstra that tries to improve on that by introducing a *heuristic function* that is able to make (hopefully) good guesses about shortest path distances. By that your Dijkstra gets a sense of direction and tries to first prioritize a search into the direction of the destination.

A simple heuristic is *as-the-crows-fly*. Note that this heuristic does not perform well on road networks and especially bad on transit networks (you often need to drive `10 mins` into the wrong direction to get on a highway that lets you arrive earlier in the end, or you need to first drive to some big city to get a good fast train). Other heuristics involve computing landmarks, they yield pretty good results but need a lot of pre-computation and space (usually not a problem).

Comment: so even we run them as as as set of Dijkstra, we still need to run 2 times if we are are looking for 2 diff paths of 4 nodes , 3 time for 3 paths of 6 nodes?  (just to confirm)

Comment: @Others The thing is, Dijkstra fixes a set of starting nodes. Once it settles a destination node, a shortest path from the starting set to this destination is known. If you let Dijkstra run until all nodes have been settled, you know all shortest paths from the starting set to the whole graph. But again, the starting set is fixed. A set-Dijkstra will consider always consider the starting node (of the set) that is closest to the destination. So if you really need the shortest path **from A** (and not from "*A or C*"), then you need to start it from **A only**. And **repeat for C**.

Comment: @Others I suggest watching tutorials, reading books or watching lessons of university courses (like [this course](https://ad-wiki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/EfficientRoutePlanningSS2012)).

Answer (score 0):

First of all Dijkstra is not the best algorithm and many heuristics outperform it in most practical implementations.

> we are only interested in the shortest paths of A,B ; C,K

Looks like you could take a look at [**A***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKYlikFAV4k&t=545s) algorithm which eliminates the nodes that will not lead you to your final destination with least cost. But it requires a good estimation (and hence the word heuristic) of the distances of various nodes to the destination.

Coming to your main question, the answer is both yes and no with some overheads. We all know that whenever a node gets removed from the min-heap its done for the algorithm.

So, as soon as your node gets removed from the min-heap, just terminate it, but that does not mean that it did find shortest distance only for the given pair. All the nodes that got removed from the min-heap before destination node are also the ones for which it has found the shortest path.

Also its possible that your destination node turns out to be the last node that is removed from the min-heap,which basically means that you have computed shortest paths from source to all nodes.

Comment: Yes. thank you for the A* algorithm. but I would like to understand Dijkstra better conceptually. So, it is not possible to find 2 paths by running the Dijkstra only one time in your point of view.(just to confirm)

Comment: It depends on the input graph.

Comment: @Others I would suggest you reading more about dijkstra until you feel very comfortable with it and you yourself can answer such questions after that.